# How to stop text transitioning off the screen

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a visual of a two ringed pie chart. 
What I'm building is the following:
 - if a sector's radians are too small for the specified text then the text is hidden. This is done and seems to work ok
 - if text is hidden then a label should appear outside the pie. This is also done when the visual is *initially* rendered.

When the radio button is pressed the labels outside the pie should transition accordingly. I've attempted the transition and slowed it to 3500 and these labels are just slowly transitioning off the screen.

How do I fix this transition?

The snippet I've added to try to create the transition starts at line 241:

```
var arcs2 = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".arcG");

arcs2.data(partition.nodes)
  .transition()
  .duration(3500)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {

    var c = arc.centroid(d),
      x = c[0],
      y = c[1],
      // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
      h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    return "translate(" + (x / h * labelr) + ',' +
      (y / h * labelr) + ")";
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");


svg.selectAll(".theTxtsOuter")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    if (d.name === 'root') {
      return;
    } else if ((d.depth === 1) && (d.dx < (d.name.length * 0.15))) {
      return d.name;
    } else if ((d.depth === 2) && (d.dx < (d.name.length * 0.1))) {
      return d.name;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
```

This is a plunk of the working(!) visual:

https://plnkr.co/edit/jYVPCL?p=preview

Here is the complete javascript used by the pie:

```
function pieChart(dataFile) {

  var plot;
  var vis;

  var width = 400,
    height = 400,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2.1,
    color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#338ABA", "#016da9", "#4c96d5"])
    .domain([0, 2]);

  var labelr = radius + 5 // radius for label anchor

  var div = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "toolTip");



  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .endAngle(function(d) {
      return d.x + d.dx;
    })
    .outerRadius(function(d) {
      return (d.y + d.dy) / (radius);
    })
    .innerRadius(function(d) {
      return d.y / (radius);
    });


  //check if the svg already exists
  plot = d3.select("#svgPIEChart");
  if (plot.empty()) {
    vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
      .append("svg")
      .attr({
        id: "svgPIEChart"
      });
  } else {
    vis = d3.select("#svgPIEChart");
    vis.selectAll("*").remove();
  }

  //group of the svg element
  var svg = vis
    .append("g")
    .attr({
      'transform': "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height * .52 + ")"
    });


  //svg element
  vis.attr({
    //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
    width: width,
    height: height
  });



  d3.text(dataFile, function(text) {
    var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
    var json = buildHierarchy(csv);

    // it seems d3.layout.partition() can be either squares or arcs
    var partition = d3.layout.partition()
      .sort(null)
      .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.SalesRev;
      });

    var path = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theArc")
      .data(partition.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "theArc")
      .attr("id", function(d, i) {
        return "theArc_" + i;
      }) //Give each slice a unique ID 
      .attr("display", function(d) {
        return d.depth ? null : "none";
      })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("stroke", "#fff")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
      })
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("opacity", 0.01)
      .style("stroke-opacity", 0.01)
      .each(stash);


    path.transition()
      .duration(PIEOBJ.transTime)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("stroke-opacity", 1)

    path
      .on("mouseout", mouseout)
      .on("mousemove", function(d) {
        div.style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px");
        div.style("top", d3.event.pageY - 25 + "px");
        div.style("display", "inline-block");
        div.html(d.name + "<br>" + PIEOBJ.formatShrtInt(d.SalesRev));
      })



    var txts = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theTxts")
      .data(partition.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("text");
    txts
      .attr("class", "theTxts")
      .attr("dx", 10) //Move the text from the start angle of the arc
      .attr("dy", 15) //Move the text down
      .style("opacity", 0)
    txts
      .transition()
      .duration(PIEOBJ.transTime)
      .style("opacity", 1);



    var txtPths = txts.append("textPath")
      // .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
      .attr("href", function(d, i) {
        return "#theArc_" + i;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        if (d.name === 'root') {
          return;
        } else if ((d.depth === 1) && (d.dx < (d.name.length * 0.15))) {
          return;
        } else if ((d.depth === 2) && (d.dx < (d.name.length * 0.1))) {
          return;
        } else {
          return d.name;
        }
      });




    /* ------- TEXT LABELS OUTSIDE THE PIE-------*/
    //var arcs = svg.selectAll(".theArc");
    var arcs = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".arcG")
      .data(partition.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "arcG");

    arcs.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {

        var c = arc.centroid(d),
          x = c[0],
          y = c[1],
          // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
          h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        console.log(c, h);
        return "translate(" + (x / h * labelr) + ',' +
          (y / h * labelr) + ")";
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d, i) {
        if (d.name === 'root') {
          return;
        } else if ((d.depth === 1) && (d.dx < (d.name.length * 0.15))) {
          return d.name;
        } else if ((d.depth === 2) && (d.dx < (d.name.length * 0.1))) {
          return d.name;
        } else {
          return;
        }
      })
      .attr("class", "theTxtsOuter");
    /* ----------------------------------------*/





    d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {


      function createValueFunc(val) {
        // currentMeasure = val;
        return function(d) {
          return d[val];
        };
      }

      value = createValueFunc(this.value);

      PIEOBJ.currentMeasure = this.value;

      var path2 = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theArc");
      path2
        .data(partition.value(value).nodes)
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween)
        .each("start", function() {
          d3.select(this)
            .on("mouseout", null) //CLEARING the listeners
            .on("mousemove", null);
        })
        .each("end", function() {
          d3.select(this)
            .on("mouseout", mouseout) //attaching the listeners
            .on("mousemove", function(d) {
              div.style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px");
              div.style("top", d3.event.pageY - 25 + "px");
              div.style("display", "inline-block");
              div.html(d.name + "<br>" + PIEOBJ.formatShrtInt(value(d)));
            });
        });

      svg.selectAll("textPath")
        .text(function(d) {
          if (d.name === 'root') {
            return;
          } else if ((d.depth === 1) && (d.dx < (d.name.length * 0.15))) {
            return;
          } else if ((d.depth === 2) && (d.dx < (d.name.length * 0.1))) {
            return;
          } else {
            return d.name;
          }
        });


      var arcs2 = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".arcG");

      arcs2.data(partition.nodes)
        .transition()
        .duration(3500)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {

          var c = arc.centroid(d),
            x = c[0],
            y = c[1],
            // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
            h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
          return "translate(" + (x / h * labelr) + ',' +
            (y / h * labelr) + ")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle");


      svg.selectAll(".theTxtsOuter")
        .text(function(d, i) {
          if (d.name === 'root') {
            return;
          } else if ((d.depth === 1) && (d.dx < (d.name.length * 0.15))) {
            return d.name;
          } else if ((d.depth === 2) && (d.dx < (d.name.length * 0.1))) {
            return d.name;
          } else {
            return;
          }
        });

      // the following deletes what was originally created and then recreates the text
      // svg.selectAll("#titleX").remove();

    });



    function mouseout() {
      div.style("display", "none"); //<< gets rid of the tooltip <<
    }

    // Stash the old values for transition.
    function stash(d) {
      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.dx0 = d.dx;
    }

    // Interpolate the arcs in data space.
    function arcTween(a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate({
        x: a.x0,
        dx: a.dx0
      }, a);
      return function(t) {
        var b = i(t);
        a.x0 = b.x;
        a.dx0 = b.dx;
        return arc(b);
      };
    }

  });


}

// // Take a 2-column CSV and transform it into a hierarchical structure suitable
// // for a partition layout. 
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
  var root = {
    "name": "root",
    "children": []
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {

    var sequence = csv[i][0];

    // var APD = +csv[i][1];
    var SalesRev = +csv[i][1];
    var Amount = +csv[i][2];

    if (isNaN(SalesRev)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
      continue;
    }
    var parts = sequence.split("-");
    var currentNode = root;
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
      var children = currentNode.children;
      var nodeName = parts[j];
      var childNode;
      if (j + 1 < parts.length) {
        // Not yet at the end of the sequence; move down the tree.
        var foundChild = false;
        for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
          if (children[k].name == nodeName) {
            childNode = children[k];
            foundChild = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        // If we don't already have a child node for this branch, create it.
        if (!foundChild) {
          childNode = {
            "name": nodeName,
            "children": []
          };
          children.push(childNode);
        }
        currentNode = childNode;
      } else {
        // Reached the end of the sequence; create a leaf node.
        childNode = {
          "name": nodeName,
          // "APD": APD,
          "SalesRev": SalesRev,
          "Amount": Amount
        };
        children.push(childNode);
      }
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(function(v) {
    v.SalesRev = 0;
    v.Amount = 0;

    v.children.forEach(function(a) {
      v.SalesRev += a.SalesRev;
      v.Amount += a.Amount;
    });
  });

  return root;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initially position them you are transforming the `text` elements.  When you transition them you are positioning the outer `g` elements.  These causes conflicting transforms.  Use:

```
arcs2.data(partition.nodes)
  .select('text') //<-- apply on child text
  .transition()
  .duration(3500)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    ...
  });
```

Updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XFZ9ch?p=preview).

Comment: excellent - now I just need to figure out how to create transitioning lines from the center of each segment to each of the labels!